# Unable to install Aimeos in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error while installing Aimeos package:

> Argument 1 passed to Aimeos\MW\Session\Laravel5::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Session\SessionInterface, instance of Illuminate\Session\Store given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\vendor\aimeos\aimeos-laravel\src\Aimeos\Shop\Base\Context.php on line 211 and defined

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What are you doing prior to getting that error?

Comment: I am calling this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php/list/     Getting this error                             ErrorException in Laravel5.php line 31:
Argument 1 passed to Aimeos\MW\Session\Laravel5::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Session\SessionInterface, instance of Illuminate\Session\Store given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\vendor\aimeos\aimeos-laravel\src\Aimeos\Shop\Base\Context.php on line 211 and defined   at Laravel5->__construct(object(Store)) in Context.php line 211

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel and Aimeos versions doesn't fit together. You are using Laravel 5.4 and it's only supported by Aimeos 2017.x, not by Aimeos 2016.10.